# Database collation in php with utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I recently moved my database from one server to another, however when I moved it I noticed that it does not receive the accents or the ñ on the new server. Do you know how I can convert it to utf8 on my new server? This is what the posts on my website look like pointing to my new database https://www.lapapaya.org/articulos.php. I hope it's clear, thank you!

Comment: Caution!  There are techniques that will mess up the data.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the existing data, and `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to show what is currently stored for `ñ` (F1 vs C3B1 vs maybe something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use codification `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` by adding at the beginning of the SQL file:

```sql
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

It seems your file is already UTF-8

On creating the database, use:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

You can put your SQL file with:

```
mysql --host=address --port=num --user=youruser --password < database.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i share the solution i gave to this issue: i had imported the database without the utf8, so all the caracters was without the ñ and the acents, so i had to creat a php script on my local and with this script replace the mistake characters with the right characters. Thats done!